# Update Mysql table row

Tags: forms, database

I'm new to Drupal and its SQL API, and I am trying to update a row in a table I created.

```
// Admin form
function admin_Form($form, &$form_state) {
  $dbval = getVals();
  $form = array();

  $form['firstname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Fornavn',
    '#id' => 'fornavn',
    '#value' =>  $dbval['firstname'],
  );

  $form['lastname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Efternavn',
    '#id' => 'efternavn',
    '#value' =>  $dbval['lastname'],
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Save'
  );

  return $form;
}

function admin_Form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $update_zoho = db_update('zoho')
    ->fields(array(
      'firstname' => $form_state['values']['firstname'],
      'lastname' => $form_state['values']['lastname'],
    ))
    ->condition('lastname', 'lastname', '=')
    ->execute();
}
```

Everything gets executed and the message gets displayed, but the row is not updated.

Can anyone point a newbie in the right direction?
These are the table structure and the values is contains.

```
    title, firstname, lastname,  city, ... lots of colums
    ------------------------------------------------------
          - Bolli    - lastname - KBH  .... 
          -          -          -     
          -          -          -   
          -          -          -
```

Comment: Hmm, something is off here.  Hard code your input values to something like "firstnameinput" and "lastnameinput" and run again. What does `var_dump($update_zoho);` output if you place it before your `drupal_set_message()`?  Use your primary key (I believe you mentioned it was 'toggleland') instead of a string in your comparison for now.

Comment: Thanks will try it as soon as I get home from work, and get back to you.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Sorry for the extreme late reply, I have not had time to look at it until now. I tried your suggestions, and hardcoding it works! So the $form_state values are not getting passed - any idea why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: First, `#value` is not a property in Drupal Form API. Secondly, add in `var_dump($form_state['values']); die();` as the first line in `admin_Form_submit()` - what is the result?

Comment: Please provide the answer as answer; the question needs to contain only the question, since this is a Q&A site.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisRockwell - this is what I figured too. Would have giving you a vote up for all the help, but I'm not allowed yet, with this little reputation.

Comment: @kiamlaluno if that was for me, I didn't post that as an answer because my answer addressed the original question (why insert wasn't working).  Why values weren't getting passed was more of a follow-up (I almost recommended a second question).

Comment: @ChrisRockwell I was talking to the OP, who added the answer inside the question. When I am not @-referring any user, and there is more than one user who commented, I am leaving a comment for the author of the post, which is always notified of any comment for the post he wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It's because I use the #value parameter in my admin_form.

From drupal dokumentation on #value:

> Description: Used to set values that cannot be edited by the user. Should NOT be confused with #default_value, which is for form inputs where users can override the default value.

So the form did get submitted, but never with the user edited value. Instead it always submitted $dbval['foo'] and it seamed like nothing changed. Changing #value to #defualt_value fixed everything. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `condition()` so that it knows which record to update.  When you don't give a condition, it just doesn't update anything.  [More Info on db_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_update/7)

The following says, "Update firstname to formvalue, lastname to formvalue WHERE the last name as stored in database is 'Bolli'".  To avoid conflicts, your table should have a field that contains a unique value for each entry, such as an auto-increment primary key.  That way, you can say "UPDATE ... WHERE id = unique_id".

```
$update_zoho = db_update('zoho')
  ->fields(array(
     //'title' => $form_state['values']['title'],
     'firstname' => $form_state['values']['firstname'],
     'lastname' => $form_state['values']['lastname'],
  ))
  ->condition('lastname', 'Bolli', '=')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply.
I tried doing what you said but still it does not update. Any ideas? 
I did: ->condition('lastname', 'datafromdatabase', '=')

Comment: From command line (or phpMyAdmin), can you do `SELECT * FROM 'zoho' LIMIT 3` and reply with the results?

Comment: Yes thank you.

I will update my first post to show you.